# Pre Complete HTML Form with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, populate

I am creating a simple page which updates a single record `tempKey=1`, single field `reqdTemp` MySQL dBase.  I have the form working fine; it updates the record, then returns to the initial form ready for the user to change the temperature again.

Q: I would like the form to be pre-populated with the existing information from the database so the user sees the current required temperature about to be changed.  I'm not sure where to start!!

The form, `updateTemperature.php`, is this:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>RPi BBQ - Set Temperature</h1>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<p>Set Temperature: <input type="text" name="setTemp" /></p><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Set Temperature" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The post script, `insert.php` is this:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$con=mysqli_connect($hh,$un,$pw,$db);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
echo 'Connected successfully';

$sql = "UPDATE PiBQ_Temp SET reqdTemp = '$_POST[setTemp]' WHERE tempKey = 1";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "1 record added";
header ('location: PiBQ_Temp2.php');

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pre-populate the form, query the database for the current value and set that in the returned HTML. So your updateTemperature.php could become something like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$con=mysqli_connect($hh,$un,$pw,$db);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
echo 'Connected successfully';

$currentTemp = 100; // some default
$sql = "SELECT reqdTemp FROM PiBQ_Temp WHERE tempKey = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $currentTemp = $row['reqdTemp'];
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
<html>
<body>
<h1>RPi BBQ - Set Temperature</h1>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<p>Set Temperature: <input type="text" name="setTemp" value="<?= $currentTemp ?>" /></p><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Set Temperature" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This makes the submit button value equal to the current temperature.  I am after the text box value in `<p>Set Temperature: <input type="text" name="setTemp" /></p><br><br>` to equal the temperature (which can be over written by the user).  Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: Oops, the code was supposed to set the value of the input field... submitted my answer too quickly it seems! I edited it to fix this

Comment: I've worked it out, I needed to set the "value=" on the text box.  The revised code for updateTemperature.php is now as thus: `<p>Set Temperature: <input type="text" name="setTemp" value="<?= $currentTemp ?>"/></p><br><br>`